# Installing opencv for java on MAC OS X and Configuring Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv

I would like to install opencv for java on my Macbook running Mac OS X and configure it to be used in Eclipsed project.

This is the version of OpenCV that I downloaded: [Latest OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html). The one that says OpenCV for Mac/Linux under Version 2.4.9.

However, when I follow the guides [here](http://sumitkumariit.blogspot.sg/2013/08/how-to-install-opencv-for-java-on-mac.html), I found that I could not continue when I was configuring Eclipse and adding external jars to the library because no opencv-249.jar or any kind of .jar files is found in the /build/ folder. All I saw is a bunch of Unix Executable files such as opencv-perl-core, opencv-perl-features2d, etc.

I was never able to make those .jar files. Anyone could help, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).  It's an opensource project in Github and a wrapper class for OpenCV.  You might get lucky with that.

Comment: Though JavaCV is sufficient, it doesn't have a lot of what OpenCV has to offer.  There may be some methods in OpenCV that are not available in JavaCV.

Answer (score 0):

I am late though but make sure your JAVA_HOME variable is set before following the instructions from the link you mentioned.

Comment: FYI, self blog promotion is not allowed, at least not in the answer! You should include essential parts from the original source into your answer, because link may no longer exist in future!

Comment: It's ok. I just shared the rule and the best way to make an answer actually interesting! because as said in previous comment, sometimes link becomes dad and so answer becomes useless!